# Optimal way to handle URL routing/Controllers in Yii

Tags: php, url-routing, yii

I am trying to develop a RESTful Yii web service. At the top level of the project I have my model that was created using a database schema + GiiX. I have a web service (ws) module that I want the web service to live in. For now the model is quite simple:

- `Product` (belongs to `Brand`, has one `Analysis`)
- `Brand` (has many `Product`)
- `Analysis` (belongs to one `Product`)

I would like to create the `urlManager` rules intelligently so that I do not have to keep adding new rules when I create new actions and/or new controllers. What I'm not sure about is how to accomplish this. Keep in mind that for now I am just trying to offer the user the ability to list them with some filters on criteria.

First, should I create a separate controller for each model I may want to work on - like `ws/ProductController`, `ws/BrandController`, `ws/AnalysisController` - or should I just have one `ws/WebServiceController` with actions corresponding to each potential return type?

With the answer to the first question in mind, what URL rules should I use to accomplish the following:

- Do an action on the `ws/*` controller(s) with no params;
- Do an action on the `ws/*` controller(s) with some params;

Also, for now, I am just using GET.

I did take a look at Yii's http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/ page on creating a RESTful API but was a bit confused on how to apply their example to my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either way. Both creating separate controllers and putting multiple actions in a single controller will work. Personally I think it will be good to create a `Ws` module and put multiple controllers inside it. One per model:

```
modules
  ws
    controllers
      ProductController
      BrandController
      …
```

This way you'll get good enough URLs automatically: `ws/product`, `ws/brand`, `ws/brand/search`, `ws/product/order` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> First, should I create a separate controller for each model I may want
>   to work on - like ws/ProductController, ws/BrandController,
>   ws/AnalysisController - or should I just have one
>   ws/WebServiceController with actions corresponding to each potential
>   return type?

I also think that depends on your application. Personally I would create an own controller for each model and maybe introduce a base class, behavior or filter, if it's needed.

> Do an action on the ws/* controller(s) with no params; Do an action on
>   the ws/* controller(s) with some params;

Assuming your module is registered as "webService" you could use these rules:

```
'ws/<_c>' => 'webService/<_c>',
'ws/<_c>/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'webService/<_c>',
```

Usage of $_GET params does not depend on your rules, you can just make the URLs nicer with them.